# Using js lib inside Portal, "TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function"

Tags: javascript, websphere-portal

When rendering the `Portal` page, I get this error ..

```
TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function
```

The page has access to `JQuery`, as I can access `JQuery` functions.
In browser I can see the js is rendered before the `pzn` footer
, so should have access to the `slick` function.
How come it doesn't?

In `pzn` header, js lib copy/pasted ..

```
<script>
/*
     _ _      _       _
 ___| (_) ___| | __  (_)___
/ __| | |/ __| |/ /  | / __|
\__ \ | | (__|   < _ | \__ \
|___/_|_|\___|_|\_(_)/ |___/
                   |__/

 Version: 1.3.15
  Author: Ken Wheeler
 Website: http://kenwheeler.github.io
    Docs: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick
    Repo: http://github.com/kenwheeler/slick
  Issues: http://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues

 */

!function(a){"use strict";"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):"undefined"!=typeof exports?module.exports=a(require("jquery")):a(jQuery)}(function(a){"use strict";var b=window.Slick||{}; ..
</script>

<div id="carouselContainer" class="slider multiple-items width"></div>
```

In `pzn` footer ..

```
<script>
$('.multiple-items').slick({
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    dots: true
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IBM Content Template Catalog` was causing conflicts. When `CTC` was disabled, the `slick` function was available.

In the end, I imported `slick.js` at the `Portal` theme level before `CTC` is initialized i.e in `theme_en.html`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too. To solve it, I changed my code from:

```
var $ = require('jquery-browserify');
var slick = require('slick-carousel');
```

to:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var slick = require('slick-carousel');
```

'jquery' was v2.1.4 whereas 'jquery-browserify' was v1.8.1.